# Spring Cloud Config: How to refresh configuration after client has been started?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Supposing I have `info.name=bruce` stored in config server A but server A hasn't started yet. Now I start a client with local configuration `info.name=Neo`. Apparently `info.name` is equal to `Neo` for this client. I think `info.name` should be replaced with `bruce` if I start config server A, but in fact `info.name` is still `Neo`.

So my question is if client starts without config server, will it retrieve configuration again when config server starts?

Comment: Have you looked into using RefreshScope http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've figured it out. The reason why client's configuration doesn't change is that the local configuration takes priority to the remote's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. Local configuration takes priority of the remote's because of the absence of the config server(Client will load local configuration first). Removing the `info.name` property from client configuration solved my problem.